# Why is File Metadata Important (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm creating a database/storage using Firebase as the backend for my website.

I have the option of having file metadata like size, cache control etc.

1. where do I get this information from? and
2. why is it important?

Answer (score 1):

A majority of the information is already populated for you (`size`, `content-type`, etc.), so you don't have to get it anywhere else.

Additional information (such as `content-disposition` or `cache-control`) end up setting the relevant headers when the file is downloaded, which can change the behavior (such as what the name of the downloaded file is, or how long the browser caches the file).

Basically, in the normal case you won't have to do anything special, but if you want custom behavior, you have these features when you need them.